# Error in deleting test cases using Azure DevOps extension API

Tags: typescript, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I have created an extension to delete the Test runs and Test cases in bulk. I'm able to delete the Test runs from separate hub page. For deleting test cases, We have created an (**ms.vss-web.action**) web action to query result windows on following target (**ms.vss-work-web.query-result-work-item-menu**). When user are deleting the test cases, its giving following error.

1. Delete https://devops.url/azure/defaultcollection/projectid/_api/test/testcases/123456 net::Err_Failed 401
2. Network Exception: TF400893: unable to contact the server. Please check your network connection and try again.
3. unhandled exception in fetch for https://devops.url/azure/defaultcollection/projectid/_api/test/testcases/123456. Type error: ail to fetch

*Scopes assigned to the extension*
Extension have following scopes: [**vs.test, vso.test_write**]

**Debugging:**

Before deleting test case, I have also tired reading & deleting the TestRun to check, if that's is also failing. But it ran successfully. But when deleting the test case, it just fail with following above errors. I have all the associated right on the DevOps Server.

```
async function DeleteTestCaseById(projectId: string, testCaseId: number): Promise<boolean> {
try {
    const result = await getClient(TestRestClient).deleteTestCase(projectId, testCaseId);
    console.log(`Deleted successfully, Testcase : ${testCaseId}`);        
    return true;
} catch (e) {
    console.log(`Error in deleting, Testcase: ${testCaseId} : ${e.message}`);
    console.log(e);
    return false;
} }
```

The SDK automatically give authorization based on scopes and identity to delete Work items. When checking the REST API documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test-cases/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP .In Security section, it's showing access token as PAT. Do I need to pass the PAT via extension.json file?

About passing PAT token: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/auth-schemes?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops#token-based-authentication

SDK Method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-devops-extension-api/testrestclient#azure-devops-extension-api-testrestclient-deletetestcase

Any Ideas/Help is welcome. Thanks for your time.

Comment: It is interesting that the test cases Delete method explicitly mentions using a PAT. Most of the other reference source [for example Pull Requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/get-pull-requests?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#oauth2) give the example as oauth2, but also work fine with PATs.